# How can I initialise & declare *optional* variables when constructing a class in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, class

I'm trying to make a game with various buildings - gym, cafe, apartment, grocery store, etc.  Each building has different and sometimes unique options - they can be a place of work (workplace) or a place to rest, or a place to improve fitness.

I want to know how I can simplify the below if-else statements or when declaring the building class, I'm sure I'm over-complicating it...!

```py
    class building():
        def __init__(self, name, x, y, isWorkplace=False, isRestArea=False, isFitnessArea=False):
            self.name = name
            self.picture_filename = self.name + ".png"
            self.image = pygame.image.load(self.picture_filename).convert_alpha()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.image.get_width(), self.image.get_height())
        if isWorkplace:
            self.workplace = True
        else:
            self.workplace = False
        if isRestArea:
            self.restArea = True
        else:
            self.restArea = False
        if isFitnessArea:
            self.fitnessArea = True
        else:
            self.fitnessArea = False
```

Comment: BTW, classes should have the first letter as a capital. So this should be `Building`.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code, i mean the `if-else` part :

```
self.workplace = isWorkplace
self.restArea = isRestArea
self.fitnessArea = isFitnessArea
```

It will do the same thing you've done with those 3 `if-else` in your code.

Comment: Excellent, this is just what I'm after.  Can you tell me - with my _init__, see how I'm passing it all the "isWorkplace=False", "isRestArea=False" etc? Is there a way for me to use something like kwargs here? I'm just wanting to add a lot more variables and it'll get very ugly...

Comment: I don't recommend you to use kwargs here, because it's not standard, in many standard libraries optional variables are defined with a default value, take a look at this link for example : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: Depending on use case you could subclass Building with those options as properties. Something like this: https://repl.it/repls/ThinFirebrickGuiltware

Comment: Wow @blueteeth, thank you! That is very helpful :)
And thanks to everyone else!